# Java: Passing Subclass Type as Parameter of Main()

Tags: java, class, subclass, program-entry-point

Within the `args[]` of `public static void main(String args[])` I would like to specify which subclass to implement. How can I convert a parameters of `args[]` (a `String`) into a class declaration?

For example, if `args[0]` = `"Subclass1"`, then somewhere below I need to declare:
`BaseClass b = new Subclass1()`

Is this possible with Java?

**EDIT**
To make this one step trickier, these subclasses are coming from an external `.jar`. Is there any way to dynamically import the subclasses, or do they need to be imported beforehand?

Comment: Can you add more details, what have you tried?

Comment: i know you can populate the args array via the command line, not sure how to populate it elsewhere

Comment: @JeffHawthorne - The args be populated from the command line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0) {
        // exceptions handling omitted
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(args[0]);
        // check before casting
        if (BaseClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            BaseClass instance = (BaseClass) clazz.newInstance();
            // use
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `className` should be the *full path* to the class, i.e. not only `Subclass1`, but `your.package.Subclass1`.

Comment: Question about this: This only can create an `Object`, right? Is it fine to cast it in that same line, or should I do that separately?

Comment: Thanks! That's what I assumed.

Comment: To make this one step trickier, these subclasses are coming from an external `.jar`. Is there any way to dynamically import the subclasses, or do they need to be imported beforehand?

Comment: @Adam_G See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60764/1225328) for further information about *why it is so difficult to load JARs dynamically at runtime*.

Answer (score 8):

The class name should be the full path to the class , i.e. [package].[classname]
You can use `Class.forName([class name]).newInstance();`

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for, but I'm going to go with @sp00m because of the more explicit declaration.

Answer (score 2):

If your main class is called `com.acme.app.Main`, and it has a subclass of `public static class Subclass1`, then use this code snippet:

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("com.acme.app.Main$"+args[0]);
Object instance = cls.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

The inner class is accessed via the `$` mark.

Note that the `cls.getConstructor().newInstance()` is more recommended than the old `cls.newInstance()`.

If you know that your inner class implements or extends a certain interface or class, then you can use `Class<MyInterface>` and `MyInterface instance` instead of general objects.

Comment: Why is `cls.getConstructor().newInstance()` recommended over `cls.newInstance()`?

Comment: Because with the first one you can catch `IllegalArgumentException` and `InvocationTargetException`, for example if you want to pass parameters.